# Setting up a dictionary from another function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that takes a dictionary, makes a copy, and then swaps the keys for the value in the copy. However, the elements of the first dictionary must come from a different function. I've got how to swap the keys/values figured out, but not howto add everything into the original dictionaries. Any ideas? (testReverse can't be edited. Only reverse can.)

```
import copy

def reverse():
    dict1 = 
    dict2 = dict1.copy()
    dict2 = {y:x for x,y in dict.iteritems()}

def testReverse():
    phoneBook = {'Doe, John': '123-1234', 'Parker, Mark': '987-9876'}
    print reverse(phoneBook) 

def main():
    testReverse()

main()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to *accept* the input dictionary as a function parameter, and you need to return the reversed result:

```
def reverse(inputdict):
    return {y:x for x,y in inputdict.iteritems()}
```

Because a dict comprehension creates a *new* dictionary altogether, the above is all that is needed; no explicit copy needs to be created.

Demo:

```
>>> def reverse(inputdict):
...     return {y: x for x, y in inputdict.iteritems()}
... 
>>> def testReverse():
...     phoneBook = {'Doe, John': '123-1234', 'Parker, Mark': '987-9876'}
...     print reverse(phoneBook) 
... 
>>> testReverse()
{'123-1234': 'Doe, John', '987-9876': 'Parker, Mark'}
```

Again, this does *not* touch the original dictionary:

```
>>> testdict = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> reverse(testdict)
{'bar': 'foo'}
>>> testdict
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: This looks good, but one question: does that create a new dictionary with the switched values, or does it edit the original dictionary?

Comment: @Machinist'sGuardianArchangel: It cannot touch the original because other than the `iteritems()` method, we don't come near the original dictionary. A dict comprehension (`{key: value for .....}`) always creates an entirely *new* dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
def reverse(d):
    return {d[k]:k for k in d}
```

Also remember that the values in your original dictionary must be *unique* otherwise you will lose key & value pairs in the new dictionary. For example:

```
>>> a = {1:-1, 2:-2, 3:-3, 4:-1}
>>> reverse(a)
{-2: 2, -1: 4, -3: 3}
```